# How to change the vertical alphabet language in contact list?

Tags: contacts, languages

All my contacts are in Greek language but the vertical alphabet is in English. How can i change it?

My phone is Samsung galaxy note 4 (not rooted), i use english language for the operating system and i don't want to change to Greek. Although i have English and Greek keyboard.

[image: This is not my phones screenshot, but imagine the contacts are in Greek and vertical alphabet language still in English]

This is not my phones screenshot, but imagine the contacts are in Greek and vertical alphabet language still in English

Comment: Can you post a screenshot, so that it's easier for us to understand your problem?